# How to capture number of commits in sonarqube?

Tags: git, github, sonarqube, code-analysis, profiler

I want to check the number of commits on daily basis. Is there any plugin in sonarqube to do the same. I use git repository for my codebase

can someone help me on the same please

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to the SonarQube SCM Stats plugin : https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-scm-stats